# Integration tests for proxy rate limiter nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I have a service proxy that is also rate limiter. I'm using nodejs, express-rate-limit (7.1.1), http-proxy-middleware (2.0.6). I wrote integration tests using jest (29.7.0) and nock (13.3.6) for this service that setup the server and send axios requests to it. I want to test a case of limiting requests (status 429) and after windowMs is passed then receive and request is sent I get status code OK.

This is my setup for the tests:

```
 beforeAll(async () => {
    process.env = {
      ...process.env,
      PORT: '8080',
      WINDWOW_MAX: '1000',
      LIMIT: '1',
      PROXY_URL: 'https://fake-url.com'
    };

    axiosAPIClient = axios.create({
      baseURL: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`,
      validateStatus: () => true
    });

    nock.disableNetConnect();
    nock.enableNetConnect('localhost');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    nock(process.env.PROXY_URL).get('/users').reply(200);

    jest.useFakeTimers({ legacyFakeTimers: true });
    teardownFn = initServer();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
    await teardownFn();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    nock.enableNetConnect();
  });
```

And this is the test itself:

```
  it('Limit request then procceed', async () => {
    expect((await axiosAPIClient.get('/users')).status).toBe(200);
    expect((await axiosAPIClient.get('/users')).status).toBe(429);

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(5000);

    expect((await axiosAPIClient.get('/users')).status).toBe(200);
  });
```

When I run the test I get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFVtr.png)

It's like jest not "waiting" the time I told it to wait. Any Help please?

I checked jest docs, I tried to use normal setTimout, I tried to test it without nock, I tried different versions of the packages, I tried to use 'modern' jest fakeTimers (then the server just didn't respons) etc.